# Botkit The URL provided is not whitelisted for messenger extensions

Tags: javascript, facebook, bots, messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I use messenger extensions in my messenger bot so that I need my domain to be whitelisted. I use this command to add my domain in whitelist:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "setting_type" : "domain_whitelisting",
  "whitelisted_domains" : ["https://example.com"],
  "domain_action_type": "add"
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?access_token=myPageAccessToken"
```

It returns:

```
{"result":"Successfully updated whitelisted domains"}
```

and then return whitelisted_domains using this command:

```
curl -i -X GET "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/thread_settings?fields=whitelisted_domains&access_token=myPageAccessToken"
```

it returns 200 status code and array which contains my domain:

```
{"data":[{"whitelisted_domains":["https:\/\/example.com\/"],"id":"425660424468922"}]}
```

but I still receive same error: `The URL provided is not whitelisted for messenger extensions`

any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you share some of your code? Are you using an example botkit project, one of the starter kits, or your own project?